# Is there a mathematical symbol for normalizing a vector with the maximum and minimum value?

Tags: normed-spaces

I normalize a vector a the following way:

`a_normed = (a - min(a)) / ( max(a) - min(a) )`

Is there a shorthand notation for this operation?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, but if you're trying to write something where this shows up a lot, you should just choose some notation, define it, then use it.

Comment: Did you mean this :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492533/abbreviated-notation-for-vector-normalized-by-its-length-unit-vector

Comment: Or this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)

Comment: Thanks, wikipedia defined a symbol for it!